# "Truffle test" fails in petshop tutorial

Tags: truffle

I don't know what this error means or how to fix it.

I try to follow the tutorial located [here](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) and when I get to the point where I have to run "truffle test" I get the following error.

```
with TestAdoption "before all" hook: prepare suite:      Error: Could not find artifacts for ''EthereumPetShopTutorial/contracts/Adoption.sol" from any sources
```

Output of `Truffle version`

```
Truffle v4.1.5 (core: 4.1.5)
Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js)
```

this is my 2_deploy_contracts.js file

```
var Adoption = artifacts.require("Adoption");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Adoption);
};
```

this is my TestAdoption.sol file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption {
  Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

  // Testing the adopt() function
    function testUserCanAdoptPet() public {
        uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(8);

        uint expected = 8;

        Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "Adoption of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
    }

}
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with the latest truffle version.
To solve this problem I had to do the following things to find a truffle version that worked.

First check for available versions of truffle with the following command.

```
npm view truffle versions
```

Then for each item on the list starting from the latest version.
I uninstalled truffle with

```
npm uninstall -g truffle
```

then installed the next oldest version with

```
npm install -g truffle@<version#>
```

then deleted the build folder

then compiled the project with

```
truffle compile
```

then ran

```
truffle test
```

if this fails move on to the next oldest version and repeat the test.

In my case a working version of truffle was 4.1.4

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the contract. It should be in the `./contracts` folder relative to your present working directory.

The compiler is going to create contract abstractions and put those in the `./build/contracts` folder you.

It's being told to go there to find `Adoption.sol` by this line:

`var Adoption = artifacts.require("Adoption");`

Hope it helps.

p.s. If this doesn't do the trick, let us know the actual verison of truffle you're using (because changes).

`$ truffle version`

Comment: Truffle version gets me v4.1.5. I edited my question with additional information. I don't know why it can't find the contract. It exists in the expected directory.

Comment: I've found that sometimes I need to give it a "kick" for reasons I don't really understand because I've never dug too deep. You can destroy the `./build` folder and then `truffle compile`.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with 4.1.5, rolling back to 4.1.4 fixed it.